# Control that acts like wrappanel and tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a wpf view with 4-5 tabs/docpanels.  What I'd like to have is the tabs/docpanels spread out dynamically when there is enough screen space and go back into a tab arrangement when there isn't enought space.  Kind of like a wrappannel that stacks.  Anyone ever done/ seen this?

Comment: If might help if you could post a mock up image or explain what you mean in greater detail. The TabControl will already wrap it's tabs as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a [UniformGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx) and play around with the rows/columns to achieve the affect desired.